# Save a value and recall it

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to pass a string to a timer and have no clue how... here is my current code.

```
    Private Sub PTID_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PTID.Click

    Dim Placeholder As String = PTID.Text
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(Placeholder)
    PTID.Text = "Copied to Clipboard"
    ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Start()


End Sub

Private Sub ClipboardTimerPaymentTech_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Tick
    PTID.Text = Placeholder
    ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Stop()
End Sub
```

What this does is, saves text to a string. Changes the textbox to alart user it has been copied, then sets it back to the original. This is the only way I can think to do it, if you have a better way, please let me know. Otherwise, how can I pass the 'Placeholder' string to the timer?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I know I could do a Threading.sleep but I do not want the program to be locked up

Comment: You could  use a label or status bar element for the notification instead of a UI control

Comment: @Plutonix I am putting it into the clipboard as the feature... I want to add it to clipboard, alert the user that it is now copied to their clipboard... and return to the original

Comment: Your Placeholder variable is local to the PTID_Click method.  That Tick sub won't see it.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah, is there anyway to transfer it to the Tick sub? Other then that only other option I see is a invisible label.

Comment: If you don't have a compile time error, then you probably have the Placeholder already declared.  Change the line `Dim Placeholder As String = PTID.Text` to just `Placeholder = PTID.Text`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the textbox Tag property instead of creating another variable

```
Private Sub PTID_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PTID.Click
    PTID.Tag = PTID.Text
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(PTID.Text)
    PTID.Text = "Copied to Clipboard"
    ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ClipboardTimerPaymentTech_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Tick
    PTID.Text = PTID.Tag
    PTID.Tag = ""
    ClipboardTimerPaymentTech.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: I went a different route, but I have never used the 'tag' command, but by your answer, it seems that would work to! Thanks for the answer!